# Error starting python in kernel in anaconda-navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I got Error while Opening kernel.
I tried to run the python from kernel to run my code but i got an error.
It is showing that **unhandled error** .
**I'm inserting SS for clear view.[image]**
**You can see it is showing No Kernel in the right side corner of the SS**

Comment: Have you done any debugging? We have very little information to work with, please provide something resembling a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like python is not installed in your conda environment.

Try

```
conda install python=3.6
```

or whatever version of python you want.